# ¿Cómo hago para que el firewall me permita acceder al servidor NodeJS de mi ordenador desde otro dispositivo conectado a la misma red local?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, firewall

Estoy usando el framework de React y cuando activo el servidor Node con

```
npm start
```

Puedo acceder desde mi navegador (localhost puerto 3000) sin problemas.

Pero si intento entrar desde mi movil conectado a la misma red wifi (usando la IP 192.168...:3000) la página no se carga. Si desactivo manualmente el firewall (McAfee) y vuelvo a intentarlo, se carga y actualiza sin problemas.

La pregunta es: *¿cómo podría lograr el mismo efecto sin tener que desactivar el firewall, permitiéndome acceder desde el móvil a la web que estoy desarrollando localmente sin generar riesgos de seguridad*

Lo que he probado hasta ahora es:

1. En *McAfee > configuracion > Firewall > Puertos y servicios del sistema* he agregado los puertos 3000-3001 y en la característica **Abrir puertos** he activado *"Solo equipos en redes domésticas y de trabajo"*. (Hay una opción extra *"Reenviar actividad del puerto a otros equipos que usan la función de conexión compartida a Internet."* que he probado tanto activada como desactivada).
2. En *McAfee > configuracion > Firewall > Conexiones a internet para programas*  establecer para el programa node.exe en *conexiones entrantes y salientes* la opción *Abrir puertos a redes domésticas y de trabajo*, así como desactivar NetGuard para ese mismo programa.

Ninguna de las dos opciones ha dado resultado. Sigo sin poder cargar la página desde el móvil. En todos los casos he reiniciado el ordenador e iniciado Node tras cada cambio de configuración del firewall.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo resolverlo? Gracias.

Comment: Para poder acceder a una dirección IP desde la red local necesitas mapear el puerto en el router. Accede a el y a través de la configuración NAT, agrega el puerto 3000 a la ip del ordenador que lo sirve.

Comment: Pero ya he podido acceder al puerto deshabilitando manualmente el firewall. Es decir, el problema no lo tengo en sí para acceder a la direccion, sino para que el firewall permita esa conexión.